# react-testing-library: some portion of debug's output is not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using react jest with react testing library to test my component.
I am facing a weird issue. I am using debug, returned by render from testing-library.

```
test('component should work', async () => {
  const { findByText, debug } = render(<MyComponent />);
  const myElement = await findByText(/someText/i);
  debug();

});
```

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot there are incomplete divs and closing tags for parents are missing.

Comment: have you tried increasing the `DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT` as mentioned in [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-helpers#debugging)

Comment: @uday no luck with DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT, still same issue.

Comment: You should be able to do so by doing: screen.debug(myComponent, Infinity);
note: you can specify "undefined" instead of "myComponent" to debug the whole document.

Answer (score 162):

You need to change the value of `DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT` env variable (default is 7000).

For example, run your tests with: `DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT=100000 yarn test`

Source: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/2653fd934f33ce19377c98029efe3e983a1c602b/src/pretty-dom.js#L50

Comment: If this isn't working for others, note that this limit is _characters_ to print and not _lines_

Answer (score 153):

I am using this version: "@testing-library/react": "^11.0.4"

able to do just like below, we can change 300000 as the max length of output.

```
debug(undefined, 300000)
```

Comment: `debug(undefined, 300000)`

Comment: @J.Munson why `undefined`?

Comment: To make typescript happy, basically. But in general, `undefined` is the standard way of omitting a parameter in Javascript.

Comment: where (file) do you call this?

Comment: answered below by @labs

Answer (score 84):

**Another option**

`screen.debug(undefined, Infinity);`

Answer (score 39):

The second argument of the `debug()` function can be used to set `maxLengthToPrint`.

E.g. to print everything in `myElement` using the [recommended `screen` approach](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-screen):

```js
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'

render(<MyComponent />);
const myElement = await screen.findByText(/someText/i);

const maxLengthToPrint = 100000
screen.debug(myElement, maxLengthToPrint);
```

See:

- [Api docs for `debug()` in render results](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#debug)
- [Api docs for `screen.debug()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#screendebug)

Comment: logged in just to upvote this answer... the others didn't explain how or where to call `screen.debug(undefined, Infinity);`, I thought we needed to pass `undefined` there since there was no explanation.

Answer (score 19):

You can use Jest Preview (https://github.com/nvh95/jest-preview) to view your app UI when testing in a browser, instead of HTML in the terminal, just by 2 lines of code:

```js
import { debug } from 'jest-preview';

describe('App', () => {
  it('should work as expected', () => {
    render(<App />);
    debug();
  });
});
```

[image: Jest Preview debug react testing library]

It works great with `jest` and `react-testing-library`.

- Introduction: https://www.jest-preview.com/docs/getting-started/intro
- Installation guide: https://www.jest-preview.com/docs/getting-started/installation

Comment: very interesting

Comment: it does not work for react native, uses jsdom and document

Comment: Wow neat✨.  For those getting started, note you must also run `jest-preview` server for this to work.

Answer (score 10):

Since the DOM size can get really large, you can set the limit of DOM content to be printed via environment variable DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT. The default value is 7000. You will see ... in the console, when the DOM content is stripped off, because of the length you have set or due to default size limit. Here's how you might increase this limit when running tests:

`DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT=10000 npm test`

Here more about debuggin on documentation

Comment: This worked out for me, just put this code before my test `DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT=10000 pnpm test "file path"`

Answer (score 6):

If none of the other answers work for you, make sure it's not your terminal limit. For example VS Code only keeps 5000 lines in buffer. Try Mac OS terminal.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```js
debug(undefined, 300000);
```

It will give you the markeup of whatever you passed into render() as:

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'

render(<MyComponent />);
```

You can read about more ways to help you with printing out the results, including prettifying the resulting markup at:

[API doc for debug](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/)

Comment: I added `screen` for this to work as I needed: `screen.debug(undefined, 300000);`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
const history = createMemoryHistory()
const { debug } = renderWithRedux(
    <Router history={history}>
        <SideBar />
    </Router>
, state);

screen.debug(debug(), 20000);
```

Answer (score 2):

By default RTL doesn't show comments, `<script />` and `<style />` tags. In my case I needed to test for a commented node in the DOM.

If you want your tests to include all the nodes, you can use [prettyDOM](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/#prettydom) like this:

```js
// render DOM with a commented node
const html = {__html: '<!--this is a commented DOM element-->'};
const element = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} />;
const { container } = render(element);

// This is what tells RLT to print all nodes!
const prettyfiedDOM = prettyDOM(container, undefined, { filterNode: () => true}) || '';

expect(prettyfiedDOM.includes('<!--this is a commented DOM element-->')).toBeTruthy();
```

Notice that the `filterNode` function always returns `true`, which tells RTL to print all DOM nodes, and hence you can test comments, styles, tags, etc. You can read more on prettyDOM source code and configure your [desired behavior of DOM filtering](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/main/types/pretty-dom.d.ts#L3-L9).

[View the live demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jest-preview-unn92k?file=src/App.test.tsx)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding on top of answer by @Haryono

Also make sure you don't have silent flag set in scripts

```
"test": "jest --config jest.config.js --silent";
```

Removing silent flag should work.

Note: I think silent flag supresses warnings and debug outputs

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure your terminal allows you to scroll back that far.  In iTerm2, I had my "Scrollback lines" set to 1000. Changed it to "Unlimited scrollback" and now life is good[image: iTerm2 scrollback lines] iTerm2:

Comment: So glad I don't have a mac